# firebase docs reference grecaptcha but never import or define it

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

From https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth:

> If signInWithPhoneNumber results in an error, reset the reCAPTCHA so
>   the user can try again:
>
> ```
> grecaptcha.reset(window.recaptchaWidgetId);
>
> // Or, if you haven't stored the widget ID:
> window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) {
>   grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
> }
> ```

But `grecaptcha` is never defined. Do I have to import it from somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like it is automatically imported by firebase. However, because I was compiling code from ES2015 I needed to add

```
/* global grecaptcha */
```

to the top of my js file to make it visible by my code.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Auth JS library will pull the grecaptcha library dynamically if it is not already included. Otherwise, if you already include it: `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js`, then it will just use that library.